# How to restore default global path for npm in Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, path, node-sass

I had changed default global path for node-sass package, but now other packages that are installed globally in a new way do not work globally! How to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run this**

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

[see documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

Comment: It would help if you explained *why* running this will help.

Comment: The prefix config defaults to the location where node is installed. On most systems, this is /usr/local. On Windows, it's %AppData%\npm